# How to transform a decimal number into binary form but still keep distance property?

Tags: encoding, compression, quantization

I am try to transform a decimal number into a binary form but still keep distance information. Such as 10-2=8 in euclidean space, but in binary case, hamming(1010-0010)=1, obviously the distance information lost a lot. Is there any possible way to transform 10 into a binary form but still keep distance property in hamming distance metric? The naive way is hamming(1111111111-0000000011)=8....

Comment: You didn't lose information by converting to binary: 1010 - 0010 is still 1000. You lost information by deciding to compute the popcount of 1000 rather than using its numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

You have found what is basically the only distance preserving map from the metric space of nonnegative integers with distance `d(x,y) = |x-y|` to the metric space of bit vectors with the hamming distance.

This isn't hard to prove: `d(x,0) = x`, so the transform of `x` must have `x` bits set. Similarly, if `x<y`, then the bits set in the transform of `x` must be a subset of the bits set in the transform of `y`.

So what you constructed is basically your only option if you really and truly must work in the space of bit vectors and hamming distance.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, actually I thought might be the best way to transform without any information lose. I think I can accept a little bit distance lose, maybe, but I will try to find a more good coding way for that. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Hx: I think if you pose as a separate question what programming problem you were trying to solve by doing this, you'd get useful responses.